# asp.net mvc 2 jqgrid add record

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

i am trying to display the 'add new record' display in jqgrid but it does not show up?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        $("#addBtn").click(function () {
            $("#list").jqGrid('editGridRow', "new", { height: 280, reloadAfterSubmit: false });
        });


      var lastsel;
      $("#list").jqGrid({
          url: '/Home/DynamicGridData/',
          datatype: 'json',
          mtype: 'GET',
          colNames: ['IdNr', 'Id', 'FirstName', 'LastName'],
          colModel: [
      { name: 'IdNr', index: 'IdNr', width: 40, align: 'left',
          editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: true }, hidden: true
      },
      { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 40, align: 'left',
          editable: false
      },
      { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', width: 200, align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: 'text', editoptions: { size: 20, maxlength: 30} },
      { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', width: 300, align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: 'text', editoptions: { size: 20, maxlength: 30}}],
          onSelectRow: function (id) {
              if (id && id !== lastsel) {
                  jQuery('#list').restoreRow(lastsel);
                  jQuery('#list').editRow(id, true);
                  jQuery("#grid_id").editGridRow(id, options); 
                    lastsel = id;
              }
          },
          editurl: "/Home/GridSave",
          pager: jQuery('#pager'),
          rowNum: 10,
          rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
          sortname: 'Id',
          sortorder: "desc",
          viewrecords: true,
          imgpath: '/content/themes/steel/images',
          caption: 'Employees'
      });



  });



</script>  


<table id="list" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
```

Comment: You have currently 0 votes. Probably you don't know that starting with 15 reputation points you have right to vote any useful answer or question on the stackoverflow.com. With the voting of answers on your own question there are simple rule described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask): "As you see new answers to your question, vote up the helpful ones by clicking the upward pointing arrow to the left of the answer". You asked already 30 questions and received many answers. Are any helpful from the answers? You can go trough answers to your old questions and vote useful one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you can see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user603007.htm) the code which you posted in general work.

I suppose that you don't included "Form Edit" module or "Common" module during [downloading](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) of the jqGrid. In you open jquery.jqGrid.min.js file which you use you can examine the comment line after the beginning of the file. You should find at list the following: `grid.base.js`, `grid.common.js` and `grid.formedit.js` after "**Modules:**. I recommend you always include "Formatter" module also. The common rule is: better include too many modules as too few.

Small additional remarks: You should not use since a long time [deprecated](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aupgrade_from_3.4.x_to_3.5) parameter `imgpath`. Default parameters like `align: 'left'` or `editable: false` can be also emitted. The `<table>` definition in the HTML code can be reduced to `<table id="list"></table>`.