# Retrieving jqgrid checkbox column values 

Tags: jqgrid, checkbox

trying to retrieve the id column of records that have their checkboxes selected in a jqgrid. I have the code below displaying the checkbox column.

```
{ name: 'checkbox', index: 'checkbox',  formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false }, editable: true, edittype: "checkbox" }
```

and the code below to edit the selected jqgrid row

```
jQuery('#list').editRow(id, true, formatEditors);
```

my question is how is it (and I am not sure if it is ) possible to go through all selected records in jqgrid after clicking on submit/any button? 
so in an event handler in my controller (mvc2) I want to access all the id values of the records selected in jqgrid.

Also I have gone through the code in [asp.net mvc 2 jqgrid add record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442262/asp-net-mvc-2-jqgrid-add-record) and I can display the add button but I cannot retrieve the rows selected by the user (checkboxes)

Any help will be greatly appreciated, as I am unable to find a similar example.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: anyone has any view about this post, I will really appreciate I have spend alot of time with no result!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the answer that finaly I put together

```
 for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

                if (inputs[i].type == 'checkbox' && inputs[i].checked) {

                    var p = inputs[i].parentNode.parentNode;
                    var id = p.id;

                           $.ajax({
                           mtype: "POST",
                           url: '<%= Url.Action("action") %>',
                            data: { actionparameter: id },
                           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                           dataType: "json",
                           async: false,
                           cache: false

              }); 
              }
          }
```

the user should also create a button and add the above code in the jquery of that button, the action will be simply an action that does the process in the controller, I hope this helps!